# How do I restart input? node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have two functions in which input is called
When I start the thread for the first time (first function), the second time it is no longer called (second function)

```
import * as readline from 'node:readline/promises';
import { stdin as input, stdout as output } from 'process';

const rl = readline.createInterface({input, output})

async function fffuncs (battlefield) {
    let input = await rl.question("Enter the first values: ");
    rl.close();
}

async function ssfuncs(battlefield) {
    rl.resume();
    let input = await rl.question("Enter the second values: ");
    rl.close();
}

fffuncs(battlefield).then(r => input)
ssfuncs(battlefield).then(r => input)
```

In the first function input is triggered and I enter values, but in the second function input no longer works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't understand how promises work... they're asynchronous. So you're starting the first one, and then immediately starting the second one. But the first one hasn't finished yet...

What you want to do is start the first promise, then wait for it to resolve before starting the second promise. Honestly, this could probably be synchronous code...

Try this:

```js
import * as readline from "node:readline/promises";
import { stdin as input, stdout as output } from "process";

const rl = readline.createInterface({ input, output });

async function fffuncs() {
  let input = await rl.question("Enter the first values: ");
  rl.pause(); // make this a pause, i guess.. not sure if this is needed
  return input; // return the user's input
}

async function ssfuncs() {
  rl.resume();
  let input = await rl.question("Enter the second values: ");
  rl.close();
  return input; // return the user's input
}

// call the first one first
fffuncs().then((result) => {
  console.log(`Result 1: ${result}`);

  // after the first one finishes, then call the second one
  ssfuncs().then((result) => {
    console.log(`Result 2: ${result}`);
  });
});

// Aleternatively, use async/await
async function main() {
  const input = await fffuncs();
  console.log(`Result 1: ${input}`);
  const input2 = await ssfuncs();
  console.log(`Result 2: ${input2}`);
}

main();
```

Comment: It works! Thanks! 
I have one question: how correct is it to make such inputs?

Comment: There's no right or wrong. Just write code that does what you want it to do! Good luck!